# Setup PPPoE connection using pppoe command only in linux

Tags: linux, networking, command, ppp

I am running debian stretch.  I am currently using Network-Manager to setup pppoe connection.  But I want to setup pppoe connection using pppoe command only.  I could not find much information or example for it. I tried with some options but it displays this data ::

```
~▒}#▒!}!}!} }3}!}$}%▒}#}%▒#}%}%}&▒▒▒Ç~~▒}#▒!}!}"} }3}!}$}%▒}#}%▒#}%}%}&ʩ}$▒~~▒}#▒!}!}#} }3}!}$}%▒}#}%▒#}%}%}&▒▒}]}#hN~~▒}#▒!}!}$} }3}!}$}%▒}#}%▒#}%}%}&▒gJ▒7▒~~▒}#▒!}!}%} }3}!}$}%▒}#}%▒#}%}%}&▒I▒}&▒6~`

sudo pppoe --help or man pppoe  

Options:
   -I if_name     -- Specify interface (default eth0.)
   -D filename    -- Log debugging information in filename.
   -T timeout     -- Specify inactivity timeout in seconds.
   -t timeout     -- Initial timeout for discovery packets in seconds
   -V             -- Print version and exit.
   -A             -- Print access concentrator names and exit.
   -S name        -- Set desired service name.
   -C name        -- Set desired access concentrator name.
   -U             -- Use Host-Unique to allow multiple PPPoE sessions.
   -W value       -- Use Host-Unique set to 'value' specifically.
   -s             -- Use synchronous PPP encapsulation.
   -m MSS         -- Clamp incoming and outgoing MSS options.
   -p pidfile     -- Write process-ID to pidfile.
   -e sess:mac    -- Skip discovery phase; use existing session.
   -n             -- Do not open discovery socket.
   -k             -- Kill a session with PADT (requires -e)
   -d             -- Perform discovery, print session info and exit.
   -f disc:sess   -- Set Ethernet frame types (hex).
   -H XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX -- Force Hardware Address (hex).
   -h             -- Print usage information.
```

I could not find any option to insert my pppoe username password.

How to connect to pppoe using pppoe command if my pppoe connection details are ::

```
username : junky567
password : 123456
service name : dsldoublebroadband
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
set pppoe.username "username provided by ISP"
set pppoe.password "password"
```